# Blank page before rotated page

Tags: landscape

I would like to have one horizontal page with charts. I try to this using pdflscape, but I have blank rotated page before page I would like rotate.
How can I fix it? My code below, pdf file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cFsqLwG1XqC3YEhDOq29yF0B6-o_gDhR/view?usp=sharing)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage {polski}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin {document}
\newgeometry{tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm, lmargin=3cm, rmargin=3cm}

\section {Section on vertical pages before horizontal page with graphics}
\section {Section on vertical pages before horizontal page with graphics}
\begin{landscape}
\section {Graphics on the new horizontal page}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{wykres1.png}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{wykres2.png}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{wykres3.png}
\caption {Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}


\section {Section on pages afrer horizontal page with graphics}
\section {Section on pages afrer horizontal page with graphics}
\section {Section on pages afrer horizontal page with graphics}


\end {document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

Change from `portrait` to `landscape` always start new page. Consequently if changes is requested somewhere middle of the page, then this page is from this point further empty. This can be avoided with use `\afterpage` command from the package `afterpage` . It fill this empty space with text, which follows to `landscape` page(s). you can eliminate white space before page in `landscape` orientation::

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document delete option `demo`
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin {document}

\section {Section on vertical pages before horizontal page with graphics}
\lipsum[1]
\section {Section on vertical pages before horizontal page with graphics}
\lipsum[2]
    \afterpage{\clearpage  % <---------------- 
\begin{landscape}
\section {Graphics on the new horizontal page}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{wykres1.png}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{wykres2.png}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{wykres3.png}
\caption {Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
    }
\lipsum[3-7]

\end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but now instead of charts I have black 
rectangles, although graphic files are in the same folder

Comment: @mateuszm, in real document remove option `demo` from package `graphicx`